# undo git changes on a file

Tags: git, git-revert

I made several commits and pushed them so, remote looks like this:

A-B-C-D---...--N

Commit B is of 4 modified files (a, b, c, d). I realized that I only want changes in file a, so I need to discard b,c,d changes. The problem is that I have already pushed the commit and made more commits that I have pushed as well. File a has been modified a lot in later commits.
Problem is that when I click on Visual Studio 2022=> Manage branches => revert, only b and c file changes have been reverted, therefore a and d are still there. I get a pop up saying that it has been an error, but there is nothing on the output window.
Question is: how do I do this using git bash?

Comment: You can first revert the commit and then split that commit into one affecting file a and another affecting the other files. You then discard the revert to file a.

Comment: Thanks but the first problem was that I couldn't revert the commit from Visual Studio

Comment: So, what is the error if you do the revert from the commandline and not VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With git bash you find the sha of the commit (use a gui, or `git log`), then you simply launch `git revert <SHA>`
This will create a new commit that revert the changes you made in the original commit.